# Getting full path location and sending it to CMD window

Tags: c#, winforms, adb, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

So I have been working on a way to save backups from adb and the best methord I came up with was this:

```
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Backup";
    saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = true;
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {   
        var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c adb backup -apk -all -f"+saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

However it is not placing the file under the test name no matter where I save it. Am I doing something wrong? 
Its also the same for my openFileDialog:

```
openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Backup";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var process = Process.Start("adb.exe", "restore"+openFileDialog1.FileName);
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot the space between -f and the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are formatted incorrectly. You are missing a space in the following line:

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c adb backup -apk -all -f"+saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

`-f"+saveFileDialog1.FileName` should be `-f "+saveFileDialog1.FileName` instead.

You should also wrap the filename in quotes to handle spaces in the file path:

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c adb backup -apk -all -f \""+saveFileDialog1.FileName+"\"");
```

Comment: ... and it won't work if there's spaces in the path. This should be done with the argument string array instead of a "command name" that contains arguments, that way everything will be escaped properly for you.

Comment: I can't believe it was something so simple had me perplexed for so long. I have to wait 10 minutes to mark this as the answer though. Thanks :) (even if I am new to c#)

Comment: thanks for the edit. All makes sense now. And marked as answer. Thanks a bunch.